# Managing jQuery click events with backbone views

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, click, coffeescript

What's the best way of creating jQuery click events for a backbone view that is rendered multiple times?  It seems like I should be using $().on() in my view's initializer, but this doesn't work unless I call it after it is rendered.

Basically, I'm rendering a table, and checking for click events on the rows.  Here's what I'm trying (in coffeescript).  This does not work -

```
class MyGridView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#myGrid'
  template: _.template(TableTmpl)

  initialize: -> 
    # $('tr',@el).on 'click', -> console.log($(@).attr('model')) # WRONG
    $(@el).on 'click', 'tr', -> console.log($(@).attr('model')) # CORRECT

  render: ->
    $(@el).empty()
    $(@el).append(@template({data: @collection.getPage()}))
```

This works, but does this create orphaned click events?

```
class MyGridView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#myGrid'
  template: _.template(TableTmpl)

  render: ->
    $(@el).empty()
    $(@el).append(@template({data: @collection.getPage()}))
    $('tr',@el).click -> console.log($(@).attr('model'))
```

**UPDATE:**

I was missing a parameter to $().on(), which is why it didn't work.  I also tried events, which seems like a better way of handling this, which worked like:

```
class MyGridView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#myGrid'
  template: _.template(TableTmpl)
  events: {'click tr', 'selectModel'}

  selectModel: ->
    model = $(e.target).parent().attr('model')
    console.log(model)

  render: ->
    $(@el).empty()
    $(@el).append(@template({data: @collection.getPage()}))
    $('tr',@el).click -> console.log($(@).attr('model'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`events` property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) for this, that's what it is for:

```
class MyGridView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#myGrid'
  events:
    'click tr': 'click'
  template: _.template(TableTmpl)
  render: ->
    @$el.empty()
    @$el.append(@template({data: @collection.getPage()}))
    @
  click: ->
    console.log($(@).attr('model'))
```

Also note the switch to [`@$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) since Backbone already has the jQuery wrapped `el` cached and that `render` usually returns the view. Furthermore, Backbone views have a [`$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) method that is a shortcut for `@$el.find(...)` so you can say `@$('tr')` instead of `$('tr', @el)`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ud6dU/

There's no need to mess around with manually binding events (in most cases). Views take care of all that for you using the view's `events` and a jQuery [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) attached to the view's `el`.

Comment: Thanks - this seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either use `live` instead of `on` or you should use backbone's `events` object.

Comment: I belive `live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: indeed. the reason I said 'live' was that the event is being attached before the element is rendered on the DOM.